# How can I securely communicate between a Java Client and CodeIgniter Server?

Tags: java, php, security, codeigniter, encryption

I need to pass commands and data between a PHP CodeIgniter based server and a Java Client.  I was thinking of using very simple encryption to encrypt / decrypt the messages.  I have run into a lot of issues trying to do very basic crypto on the Java side.

Either I would like some help with the Java side of the Crypto, or a different idea to secure communication between the Client and Server.

The data is not sensitive and can be sent in the clear, as long as I can ensure it is coming from the correct source.  I was thinking of using the basic encryption as an authentication measure that would not be circumvented by a replay attack.  But I could be going about this all wrong.

Any help or comments are appreciated.

Comment: If you need security between client and server, use https.... that gives you guarantee of source, especially if you check the certificate

Comment: I can see how that would ensure data from the server to the client is verified.  How would I use that to verify the Java Client is sending the proper data.  In this case the Java client will be freely available for download.  I want to try to prevent someone from sending invalid data to the PHP server. If all the TLS authentication is done in the Java Client then it would still be open to error.  Its more about verifying the Java Client is the proper one, not securing the data in the transfer its self.  Every Java Client is a different entity, I need to verify each client's data separately.

Comment: It's up to the PHP server to be resistant to abuse, so it's the server's job to validate all input.  After all, you can't garantuee that someone won't just try to attack the system with a CURL session.  Don't forget that PHP can accept connections from any software that can initiate a connection in one of the protocols it supports.

Comment: You need message authentication, using MAC, HMAC or a signature. Encryption is to provide confidentiality, not message integrity or authentication. Note that you need to have a safe key distribution method, and that your Java client is running in a relatively secure environment. You might want to read up on crypto before performing such a task. Using SSL/TLS might be a better option (but be sure your cipher suites all include a MAC).

Comment: Build a REST service on your server side, then you can start XML transaction via http with http authentification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method of guaranteeing that the data your server is received comes from a legitimate version of your Java app. If you're using any form of encryption, the key must be stored somewhere in your application bytecode. Also, it is not very difficult to hack the client-side application and let it send invalid data.

The correct approach is to keep in mind, on the server side, that your data might not be coming from the correct source and therefore you'll have to validate all data in order to make sure nothing illegal is being done.

If you just want to guarantee that legitimate users using your client application can be certain that they are communicating with your server, you can use HTTPS or some other method using asymmetric encryption.